# Trying to add space between specific subplot2grid, not all

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following creates 10 subplots:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (0, 0), colspan=4, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (0, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (0, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (1, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax9 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (1, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)

ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (2, 0), colspan=4, rowspan=2)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (2, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (2, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax8 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8), (3, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax10 = plt.subplot2grid((4, 8),(3, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

[image]

I wanted to add a line of space between the top set of subplots and the bottom set of subplots. I tried adding a row as follows (which worked for me before but isn't now for some reason), and shifting all the subplots in the bottom down by one row:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (0, 0), colspan=4, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (0, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (0, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (1, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax9 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (1, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)

ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (3, 0), colspan=4, rowspan=2)
ax6 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (3, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax7 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (3, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax8 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8), (4, 4), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
ax10 = plt.subplot2grid((5, 8),(4, 6), colspan=2, rowspan=1)
```

However, it generates two empty subplots for me that I haven't requested in that empty row in between (giving me a total of 12 subplots). I just want an empty row or spacing between the two groups.

[image]

Comment: This should not happen. When running the code as it is (adding `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the top), I get 10 subplots as expected. Make sure you do not have any code in there, which would interfere with your subplot creation.

Comment: u were right there was something in the code that was confusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get what you want using `gridspec`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5,8)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2,0:4])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:1,4:6])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:1,6:8])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:2,4:6])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:2,6:8])


ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:5,0:4])
ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:4,4:6])
ax8 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:4,6:8])
ax9 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:5,4:6])
ax10 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:5,6:8])

plt.show()
```

This gives the following result:

[image: result of above code]

Comment: Not sure if this solves the problem though. Since the code from the question using `subplot2grid` is essentially the same and is equally expected to give the same result, the problem of the OP is rather in some part of the code not shown in the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I agree. I just had wanted to try it out for myself and as I had the code already, I thought I'd post it as an alternative. Anyway, without an MCVE it won't be possible to pin down the real problem.